# DalliError: No server available but still write / read fragment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, dalli

I was checking out my production.log on my server and sees these lines comes every time the code is suspected to read or write cache:

```
DalliError: No server available  
Write fragment views/artists/522-...  
DalliError: No server available  
Read fragment views/artists/92-...
```

Why and is that something i need to be worried about?
Im using dalli (2.6.2), cache_digests (0.2.0), rails (3.2.11) and memcached (1.4.2).

When I installed memcached, I happened to use sudo, can that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

That was probably related to the fact that Dalli was defaulting to localhost

It's solved since 2.6.4 - https://github.com/mperham/dalli/pull/266